# Pass information's from PHP to node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

How i can pass current logged in user informations from PHP to node.js?

For example: assumimg this chat app (http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) how i can bind PHP with the nodejs app, so it would be possible to tell which user sent this message from the php apche server.

I was able to connect NodeJs from my PHP application by just using the

```
io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
```

and custom events all works great. but i can't understand how i can share the logged in username etc from PHP to node.js?

After googling i've found DNODE (http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/) and now i am totally confused.

I think Express Framework would do this but i want to do things with PHP and Node.

Please share some ideas, i am just a beginner at node js.

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically referring to accessing session data stored by PHP, you might consider using a database (for example, [redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler) or [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#60316)) for storing your sessions instead. This way you can just access the session data directly without having to involve PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the idea :) also i was wondering if it is possible to send notifications to the user using nodejs on a php based app? like when the user has a comment in her post then she will get an instant notification!!